# Howto upgrade ruby on a Ubuntu 14.04.2 (Trusty) on a Raspberry Pi 2 (armhf architecture)

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, raspberry-pi, ruby

I need to install json via

```
# gem install json --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

but I get as result

```
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    json requires Ruby version ~> 2.0.
```

I use Ubuntu Trusty ([this image](http://www.finnie.org/software/raspberrypi/2015-04-06-ubuntu-trusty.zip)) and for some reasons I cannot switch to a more recent distribution like Xenial (16.04). Ubuntu Trusty is a must. The hardware architecture of the Raspberry Pi 2 is not quite helpful because 2rd party  repositories like [ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng](https://www.brightbox.com/docs/ruby/ubuntu/) do not support armhf.

I just have Ruby 1.9.3 available.

```
# ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [arm-linux-eabihf]

# lsb_release -dc
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Codename:       trusty

# uname -i
armv7l
```

What is the most simple way to install a newer Ruby version?

**Update: Solution**

These lines worked perfect for me:

```
# \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash
# source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
# rvm get stable
# rvm install ruby-2.1.5

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ruby ruby /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby 400 \
 --slave /usr/bin/rake rake /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rake \
 --slave /usr/bin/ri ri /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ri \
 --slave /usr/bin/rdoc rdoc /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rdoc \
 --slave /usr/bin/gem gem /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/gem \
 --slave /usr/bin/irb irb /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/irb

# ruby --version
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [armv7l-linux-eabihf]
# gem --version
2.4.8
```

Comment: You could always build it from source, is there any reason you cannot do that?

Comment: Compiling from source is always possible in principle but I hoped that there is a more comfortable way. Right now  I give [RVM](https://rvm.io/) a try. A perfect result would be Ruby 2.1

Comment: I found [this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1010/can-i-install-the-ruby-version-manager)